# How can you update a query result performed by a query using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to update a "date" result from a query I perform. 
Here is the code im using to perform the initial query:

```
<?php

include ("config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM redmine.issues join redmine.projects ON issues.project_id=projects.id where projects.name='".$_SESSION['name']."';");

echo "<table border='0' width='80%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='2' id='datatable' class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped'>
<tr>
<th width='50%' align='left'>Milestone</th>
<th width='25%' align='left'>Template Date</th>
<th width='15%' align='left'>Due Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='left'><input class='hidden' type='text' name='subject' id='subject' value='" . $row['subject'] . "'>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='left'>" . $row['created_on'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='left'><input type='text' name='due_date' id='due_date' value='".$row['due_date']."'></td>";
echo "<td align='left'><input type='submit' value='Submit New Date'></td>";
echo "</tr>";                                                      
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br />";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This will give me this result:

```
----------------------------------------
Milestone   | Created Date | Due Date   
----------------------------------------
Milestone 1 | 01/22/2015   | 01/22/2015 
----------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to then type in a new date in the "Due Date" textbox for each milestone and update the due date in my mysql table for that milestone.

Any help is appreciated!

I now have this script.. but it only seems to update the last mysql query result. for example, if I have 5 milestones retrieved, I can only update the last mile stone date. If I try to update the other 4 milestone dates, they wont update.

```
<?php 

include ("config.php");

// Get values from form 
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$due_date=$_POST['due_date'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE redmine.issues join redmine.projects ON issues.project_id=projects.id SET issues.due_date='$due_date' WHERE issues.subject='$subject' AND projects.name='".$_SESSION['name']."'");

// close connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: What did you try already? What are you having trouble with? Creating an input field? Processing the form the input field is part of? Writing the update query?

Comment: Hi RST, thank you for responding. I am trying to figure out how to update the due date field with an update query. I think im confusing myself with that fact that more than one milestone is returned and I would need to update the date for one or more corresponding milestones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a input[type="text"] field like this:

```
<input type="text" value="something" id="DueDate" data-id="12" onchange="function_update()"/>
```

In **function_update()** get current id by **data-id="12"** and value by **id="DueDate"** using ajax for onchange event.